# Convert duration from days to time in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a sum column with calculated duration. The values are corrected but they are reflecting in `Days` format instead of `hh:mm:ss`.

How can I convert the column format in PowerBI `Edit Queries` from `Days` to Time(`hh:mm:ss`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a native format that does that. You can create a custom column to format it as text however you'd like though.

```
= Text.From(Number.RoundDown(Duration.TotalHours([SumColumn]))) & ":" &
      Text.From(Duration.Minutes([SumColumn])) & ":" &
      Text.From(Duration.Seconds([SumColumn])))
```